# Error in f1(x) : argument "b" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, data-mining, dataset, data, activation-function

```
f1 <- function(a,b,c,d,e,f) { 

  -111.605*a-208.39+(14.882-b)^2+35.29813*c-.001251205/d-1.050695*e+11.63420*f
}
```

---

```
x = matrix(c(1:66), byrow = T, ncol = 6)
f1(x)
```

An error of the following occurs:

> Error in f1(x) : argument "b" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the answer:

```
f1 <- function(a,b,c,d,e,f) { 

  -111.605*a-208.39+(14.882-b)^2+35.29813*c-.001251205/d-1.050695*e+11.63420*f
}
x = matrix(c(1:66), byrow = T, ncol = 6)

for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  new_out[i] <- f1(x[,1][i],x[,2][i],x[,3][i],x[,4][i],x[,5][i],x[,6][i])
}

new_out <- as.data.frame(new_out)
```

or instead of that for loop you can use this:

```
new_out2 <- as.data.frame(f1(x[,1],x[,2],x[,3],x[,4],x[,5],x[,6]))
colnames(new_out2) <- "new_out"
```

Reason for the error is, it was taking x as 1 element. So, I called this function using its name.

Do let me know if you any issues.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that the newdata X must have the same column names of the functions. But thank you so much for your reply.Appreciated that.

Comment: welcome, not same name, same number of coulmns.